# Can not pull docker images from docker-registry when using ceph storage

Tags: docker, docker-registry, ceph

When I use docker-registry and ceph, I have an question, please help me.

```html
    [xxxxx@localhost ~]$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
483f958837a6        registry:2.6        "/entrypoint.sh /etc/"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes                           docker-registry
37801ea7b3d4        ceph/daemon         "/entrypoint.sh rgw"     2 hours ago         Up 48 minutes                           mad_euclid
f913bdf3265c        ceph/daemon         "/entrypoint.sh osd_d"   3 hours ago         Up 48 minutes                           compassionate_knuth
cd4fa0b0b8db        ceph/daemon         "/entrypoint.sh mon"     3 hours ago         Up 49 minutes                           adoring_minsky
```

This is status ceph and docker-registry,

```html
[xxxxx@localhost ~]$ sudo docker exec cd4fa0b0b8db ceph -s
    cluster 3f469876-46c7-4b0f-a507-f83d54318d3e
     health HEALTH_WARN
            88 pgs degraded
            88 pgs stuck degraded
            88 pgs stuck unclean
            88 pgs stuck undersized
            88 pgs undersized
            recovery 257/514 objects degraded (50.000%)
     monmap e4: 1 mons at {localhost.localdomain=10.76.6.30:6789/0}
            election epoch 6, quorum 0 localhost.localdomain
        mgr no daemons active
     osdmap e32: 3 osds: 3 up, 3 in
            flags sortbitwise,require_jewel_osds,require_kraken_osds
      pgmap v350: 152 pgs, 12 pools, 70536 kB data, 257 objects
            472 MB used, 98490 MB / 98962 MB avail
            257/514 objects degraded (50.000%)
                  88 active+undersized+degraded
                  64 active+clean
  client io 1433 B/s rd, 0 op/s rd, 0 op/s wr
```

ceph status is HEALTH_WARN, I can push images to the ceph

the config.yml for the docker-registry

```
sudo docker run -d -v `pwd`/config.yml:/etc/docker/registry/config.yml --net=host --name=docker-registry registry:2.6
```

```html
version: 0.1
storage:
    swift:
       authurl: http://{my-ip}:8080/auth/v1
       username: registry:swift
       password: e3aXlPELjOIC06cbwqwGEQjJrJUxmmya3deuNPVf
       container: registry
    cache:
       layerinfo: inmemory
    maintenance:
       uploadpurging:
           enabled: false
    delete:
       enable: true
http:
    addr: {my-ip}:6000
    debug:
        addr: {my-ip}:6001
    headers:
        X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
health:
    storagedriver:
        enabled: true
        interval: 10s
        threshold: 3
```

when I push images to the registry, it is corrent, but when I pull images, it is wrong.

```html
bj-m-xxxxxxa:~ xxxxxxa$ docker push {my-ip}:6000/cetos:v7
The push refers to a repository [my-ip:6000/cetos]
9b198ff9ff5b: Pushed
v7: digest: sha256:d7f3db1caf4ea76117abce89709ebfc66c9339e13866016b8b2e4eee3ab4bea0 size: 529
bj-m-xxxxxxa:~ xxxxxxa$ docker images
REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
my-ip:6000/cetos   v7                  98d35105a391        8 days ago          193 MB
centos                  latest              98d35105a391        8 days ago          193 MB
ceph/demo               latest              d170e0f9cff7        6 months ago        1.01 GB
bj-m-xxxxxxa:~ xxxxxxa$ docker rmi my-ip:6000/cetos:v7
Untagged: my-ip:6000/cetos:v7
Untagged: my-ip:6000/cetos@sha256:d7f3db1caf4ea76117abce89709ebfc66c9339e13866016b8b2e4eee3ab4bea0
bj-m-xxxxxxa:~ xxxxxxa$ docker rmi centos
Untagged: centos:latest
Untagged: centos@sha256:be5b4a93f116a57ab3fd454ada72421eac892a3a4925627ac9a44f65fcd69cf8
Deleted: sha256:98d35105a391b7e429e2c51ea137670f7ec0d4341a42c985772a75cfa43ad85f
Deleted: sha256:9b198ff9ff5b314b0367bea097cfc320046b36ebfa6c9a1e2ba2a78665d58d87
bj-m-xxxxxxa:~ xxxxxxa$ docker pull 10.77.6.30:6000/cetos:v7
v7: Pulling from cetos
4969bbd91a1e: Retrying in 5 seconds
error pulling image configuration: unexpected EOF
```

The error: error pulling image configuration: unexpected EOF occurs, why, how can i solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not use ceph docker images ceph/daemon, use the http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/start/quick-ceph-deploy/ way to install,I can pull the images sucessfully.

I think the image ceph/daemon has some questions, do not use for production.